# Django Rest Framework: Request user es siempre un usuario anónimo

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, jwt

Estoy utilizando Djando Rest Framework y Json Web Token.

- Mi modelo user simplificado:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=65, unique=True)
    idtipousuario = models.ForeignKey('TiposUsuario', on_delete=models.PROTECT,db_column='idtipousuario', null=True, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

- Serializer.py:

```
 class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tipousuario = TiposUsuariosSerializer(source='idtipousuario', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields='__all__'
        extra_kwargs={ 'password': { 'write_only':True } }
```

- apiview.py

```
class UserCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = ([])
    permission_classes = ([permissions.HasAPIKey, TipoUsuarioPermission])
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

- permissions.py

```
class TipoUsuarioPermission(BasePermission):
    message = "Back: No tiene permiso para crear ese tipo de usuario."

    def has_permission (self, request, view)        

        if not request.user.is_anonymous:
        # Si un usuario logueado es de tipo administrador puede crear usuarios de otros tipos (excepto de idtipoclient = 1)
            if request.user.idtipoclient != 'administrador':
                return False
            else:
                return request.data['idtipoclient'] != 1
        else: 
        # Si el usuario es anónimo el tipo de usuario que se esta creando en la solicitud debe ser tipo 1 de lo contrario no tiene permiso para crearlo (registro del usuario)
            return request.data['idtipoclient'] == 1
```

Estoy creando un administrador de usuarios. En mi aplicación se pueden crear usuarios de varios tipos. Los tipos son:

- administrador
- inspector
- punto de venta
- ciudadano

Un usuario anónimo solo puede registrarse. En este caso se crea un usuario de tipo ciudadano. 
Es decir un usuario anónimo sólo puede crear un usuario tipo ciudadano (idusuario = 1).

Un usuario administrador se loguea en mi aplicación y puede crear usuarios de todos los tipos excepto un usuario tipo ciudadano.

Lo que intento hacer es un permiso global utilizando la clase BasePermission para validar que un usuario autenticado solo pueda crear ciertos tipos de usuarios y un usuario anónimo otro tipo de usuario.

El problema es que request.user siempre es anónimo aunque en el header de la solicitud vaya el token de acceso.

Probablemente algo estoy entendiendo mal. También he intentado modificar la vista de la siguiente manera, pero el problema persiste:

- apiview.py

```
class UserCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = ([IsAuthenticated, permissions.HasAPIKey, TipoUsuarioPermission])
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda o indicio de lo que estoy haciendo mal. Gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: Estás enviando el JWT en el header ?

Comment: Encontré el problema en el interceptor que desde mi frontend añade los headers. Justo venia a dar de baja la pregunta. Era ese el problema, no estaba enviado el JWT . Como lo probé con postman, en donde si envíaba el token y tenia el mismo problema pensé que el error lo tenía en la back pero seguro no lo probé bien. Muchas gracias ! ya esta solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

Problema solucionado. El error lo tenia en el frontend, en el interceptor que añade los headers, por lo que no se estaba enviando el JWT.

Dejo la pregunta por si le es útil a alguien más.